# I'm not getting the data from the $_FILES["file"]["type"] and $_FILES["file"]["size"] even though $_FILES["file"]["name"] is retuning the filename

Tags: php, html, file

In the `$_FILES` global variable, when i used

1. `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` : I am getting the name of the file which i am uploading.
2. `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` : Here i am getting blank data. But when i used ISSET function on this variable ( `isset($_FILES["file"]["type"])` ), it's returning 1.
3. `$_FILES["file"]["size"]` : It returning zero.

I really don't know, what is the real cause of this issue? 
(As i am observing this issue is not happening in case of creating a new record, i.e., add a new record in the table and upload the specified file to the server.
But, the said problem is happening only when i try to edit an existing record i.e., replacing the old file with a new file by uploading the new file.)

Comment: check `$_FILES['userfile']['error']` for errors  http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Thanks Galen .... I found the reason why it was happening? The upload file was exceeding the max. file size limit.

Comment: @Galen Thanks for this. You saved me a lot of debugging time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)...

`If no file is selected for upload in your form, PHP will return $_FILES['userfile']['size'] as 0, and $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] as none.`

Also, isset returns true when you check `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` because it is set, that is the variable exists, but its value is empty.  Instead of isset, use `if (empty($_FILES["file"]["type"]))`

You should not trust `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` either as it can either be spoofed by the user, or just plain wrong.

Do you get the above errors only if no file was uploaded?  Or was a file uploaded?  It may be that there was an error with the file so those parts of the array were not set.

Post some more code and a more descriptive explanation of the problem and how you can reproduce it and we can help more.

Comment: The file is selected, as i can see the file by using the 'echo "Filename = " . $_FILES["userfile"]["name"], but when i used the type and size index name, i didn't get any data related to the said file.

Comment: I don't know, whether is it my testbed issue as i am using WAMP on my standalone Machine for my entire project (One single machine acting as both web server and client.) I'll be very grateful, if anybody in this group share me their knowledges with me on this issue. Thanks

Comment: Is `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` set? And if so, are the contents correct if you call file_get_contents on it?

Comment: Here is my sample code :  if( isset($_FILES["userfile"]["name"]) ) { if( trim($_FILES{"userfile"]["name"]) != "") { if($FILES["userfile"]["type"] == "aplication/pdf" && $_FILES["userfile"]["size"] > 2000000) { echo "FIle is PDF and its size is less than the specified max size."; } else { echo "File is either not PDF or is greater than the max. file size."; }

Comment: Does `$_FILES['userfile']['error']` show something other than 0?

Comment: Thanks Drew.... I found the reason why it was happening? The upload file was exceeding the max. file size limit. The manual that you have provided to me, is found very useful in debugging my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something that tripped me up the other day - make sure that the destination dir where the tmp file is written to is accessible to php. It should be within the open_basedir and writeable by your server (apache/nginx etc.) :)