# php video upload issue

Tags: php, video, file-upload, upload

I am not getting uploaded video's file type and file size for specific types like .MPG, .mov

Here is the simple code:

```
<form id="userPostVideoForm" name="userPostVideoForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="filePostVideo" name="filePostVideo" />
<input type="submit" id="submitUserPostVideo" name="submitUserPostVideo" class="button" value="Upload Video"/>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitUserPostVideo'])){
    print_r($_FILES['filePostVideo']);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array ( [name] => smoking-dog.MPG [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 )
```

For .mp4 and .3gp it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a whole lot of information to go off of but here are some suggestions:

This sounds like it might be more of a server configuration issue. I'd try to upload something smaller first such as an image to test with.

Once you have file uploading working correctly, see if it's a file size limitation issue

Start here with this sitepoint tutorial to see if your php.ini settings are correct.

http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/

Comment: If you're using shared hosting don't have access to your php.ini and need to up your file upload limit, you can do so with .htaccess or in your application using ini_set the tutorial does go over this.

Comment: I am uploading video having size of 2 MB. I don't think this is the size issue.

Comment: This sounds very familiar to this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281080/im-not-getting-the-data-from-the-filesfiletype-and-filesfiles. This also has the link the PHP manual for your reference.